# 2D geometry calculation - on flat surface

Tags: javascript, geometry, 2d, turfjs, flatten-js

I am trying to do some geometry calculation (*e.g distance from point to line*) on 2D planar planes.

Currently investigating `turfjs` to calculate distance from point to line.

---

### Code

**distance.js:**

```
// hello
var turf = require('@turf/turf')

init();

// init,
function init() {
    distance();
}

function distance() {
    // line
    let line = turf.lineString([
    [0, 0],
    [3, 4]
    ]);
    console.log(line);

    // point
    let point = turf.point([3, 0]);
    console.log(point);

    // calculate distance from point to line, using planar,
    let dis = turf.pointToLineDistance(point, line, {
    units: 'degrees',
    method: 'planar'
    });
    console.log("distance: %f", dis);
}
```

---

### Output

> distance: 2.398995395932417

If I change point to `[30, 0]` and line to `[0, 0], [30, 40]`, then the output is:

> distance: 25.741472914575986

The program is using `degrees` as unit, and `planar` as method.

The expected results are `2.4` and `24`, but it's not.

---

### Question

- So, does that means those points are on a curved surface, instead of a flat plane?
- Is it possible to define points & lines & polygons in flat plane, instead of the curved surface?
- If not, then it there another similar tool to perform this task?

Comment: But I don't see 'planar' option here: http://turfjs.org/docs#pointToLineDistance  Why do you use geo-library for plain geometry?

Comment: @MBo You can find the options here: https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/tree/master/packages/turf-point-to-line-distance

Comment: @MBo I am looking for a proper library, just investigating turfjs, do you know any library that could be a better fit for this requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [turf.js source code for point to line distance](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/blob/master/packages/turf-point-to-line-distance/index.ts), you'll see that it calculates planar distances along a [rhumb line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhumb_line), and that's not what you would expect in planar geometry.

To achieve what you want, you could implement the [equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line#Line_defined_by_two_points) yourself, something like

```js
function pointToLineDistance(line, p0) {
    var p1 = line[0],
        p2 = line[1];

    var x0 = p0[0], y0 = p0[1],
        x1 = p1[0], y1 = p1[1],
        x2 = p2[0], y2 = p2[1]


    return Math.abs(
        (y2 - y1) * x0
        - (x2 - x1) * y0
        + x2 * y1
        - y2 * x1
    ) 
    /
    Math.sqrt(
        (y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1)
        +
        (x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1)
    );
}

console.log(
    pointToLineDistance([[0, 0], [3, 4]], [3, 0]),
    pointToLineDistance([[0, 0], [30, 40]], [30, 0]),
);
```

Or if you prefer a library, something like [flatten.js](https://github.com/alexbol99/flatten-js) could help you :

```
let Flatten = require('flatten-js');

let {point, line} = Flatten;

let l = line(point(0, 0), point(3, 4));
let p = point(3, 0)
let d = p.distanceTo(l);

console.log(d[0]);
```

Comment: For this single operation this answer is great, but there are many other operations needed (e.g intersection of 2 polygons, area of a polygon), so I am still looking for a easy to use library to perform these operations, not limited to Javascript.

Comment: I am investigating flatten-js and some other tools, you might also be interested in Stefano's answer.

Answer (score 1):

`Turf.js` is meant to be used on Mercator (web, 2D) maps but for calculations it's based on [WSG84](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System) (3D) standards, i.e. considers the Earth a spheroid. Some times though, particularly on wide areas, representations and operations on spherical features on a 2D map return unintuitive or unexpected results; in these cases we adopted [Rhumb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhumb_line) or even euclidean operations (hence the `planar` option for `pointToLineDistance` for example), which sometimes could result in reduced accuracy.

So, to answer to your first question, Turf considers your points on a curved surface and to answer the your second it is not possible to instruct Turf to work on a flat surface.

As for alternative libraries you might want to consider using more than one; in addition to the already suggested `flatten.js` you could take a look at [`jsts`](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts) for operations like union and intersect.

If you are not limited to Javascript, you might want to take a look to Python [`Shapely`](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely), which in my understanding as a very powerful and reliable tool.

Both the above libraries are used in few Turf packages or used as reference for implementation and/or result.
A note on `jsts`, it has shown [some issues](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20jsts) in Turf, but you might be fine with it depending on the complexity of your cases.